# email notification if cell is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

need help with google script. I have multiple row [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqmhWQ_A7q_adFU2cnRKRlZGSlFkWF9WeXhqblFFWmc&usp=sharing).

> **Need a script that does the following:**
>
> If any cell in column G has been changed, then send email notification
>   to custom address with information from this row: information from
>   cell D and new value of cell G.

**UPD**

I found useful information:

```
function emailNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipient = "me@gmail.com";
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on cell: «' + cell + '» New cell value: «' + cellvalue + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
};
```

This script tracks the changes in the entire table. And I would like track changes only in column G, and get values ​​from column D.

> **Question:**
>
> How to get the value of the cell in column D when the value has
>   changed cell in column G

**Finally script — answer to my question**

[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqmhWQ_A7q_adFU2cnRKRlZGSlFkWF9WeXhqblFFWmc&usp=sharing)

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "me@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('G')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Set trigger on onEdit and script will work fine

Comment: Please post a sample of the code you have tried.

Comment: see edit in my answer please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should search this forum before posting questions; I did search on *email+cell* and got a few results :

For example, [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768532/how-to-attach-onchange-cell-value-event-script-to-google-sheet/13770980#13770980) does almost exactly what you want to do.

EDIT following your edit :

use an `IF` condition.

Something like this :

```
    var cellG = ''
    if(cell.indexOf('D')!=-1){ // = if you edit data in col D
cellG = sheet.getRange('G'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
// add more condition if necessary and/or send your mail (cellG contains the value in column G of the active row
}
    Logger.log(cellG)
```

Comment: There was also [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991711/onedit-for-copy-paste-doesnt-work) which will help you with the "information from this row" part of your request.

Comment: Serge insas, thx! it works. but for my question had to swap the D and G row.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to track a cell-change event is to use the event object "e" with onEdit trigger. The event object contains the range that was edited and hence you can always get the content of the cell that was changed.

```
function sendNotification(e){
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

NOTE: The function name shouldn't be onEdit which is a special name in apps script. The onEdit function won't allow to send email because of **LIMITED** authMode.

[Here is an apps script](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2016/09/send-notification-email-if-cell-is.html) which allows to send an email if a cell is edited in a specific range. It also allows to send the entire row, entire column or a custom range to be sent in the notification email.