# Email notification if specific cell is changed and add another cells value to message without change tracking

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-notifications

What i did:

If any cell in column M has been changed, then email notification has been sended to specify adres from column N at the same row. But i also need some specify body text from other columns at the same row. I did something that is working but it also causes that if other declared columns (such as project, customer, task, executor) has been changed the emil has been send to.

What i need:

Just track change in only one "M" column and put at the body of email additional data from other columns but from the same row. And (thats the point) did not track change at other columns, email should be send only if changing column M.

Probably it would be easy, but i'm twisted...

I bulid this script based on:

- [email notification if cell is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336907/email-notification-if-cell-is-changed)
- [how to attach onChange cell value event/script to google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768532/how-to-attach-onchange-cell-value-event-script-to-google-sheet?lq=1)
- [Restrict notifications sent for changes referenced in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225720/google-apps-script-restrict-notifications-sent-for-changes-referenced-in-colum?lq=1)

My script:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var sendto = '';
      if(cell.indexOf('M')!=-1){ 
      sendto = sheet.getRange('N'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
      }   
  var project = ''; 
      project = sheet.getRange('C'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()   
  var customer = '';
      customer = sheet.getRange('D'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()      
  var task = '';
      task = sheet.getRange('E'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()      
  var executor = '';
      executor = sheet.getRange('F'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() 
  var deadline = '';
      deadline = LanguageApp.translate(Utilities.formatDate(sheet.getRange('I'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() , "GMT" , "EEEE, dd MMMM YYYY" ),'en','pl')
  var status = '';
      status = sheet.getRange('M'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()         
  var mysubject = status + ' | ' + project + ': ' + task + ' - ' + ss.getName() + ' update';
  var mybody = '\nStatus: ' + status + '\n\nproject: ' + project + '\ncustomer: ' + customer + '\ntask: ' + task + '\nexecutor: ' + executor + '\nDeadline: ' + deadline + '\n\n' + ss.getName() + ': \n' + ss.getUrl();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:sendto, 
    subject:mysubject,
    body:mybody});
};
```

Comment: So did that help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite what I need, I need to look for another solution ... but thanks for your time and possible solutions that you offer. Problem is that I have a lot rows and I need to work fast with few people at the same time.

Comment: Leaving my answer unchecked means you want future readers to know that my answer is wrong.  Checking my answer as correct means future readers could benefit from it, even if it did not exactly solve your problem. Also, an "up vote" means you benefited from or otherwise appreciated the help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example script that you should be able to see at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11u0xkdtPlQsnVppCnPYM0CHuCTPLdmN8PcFlaW08lNw/edit#gid=0

You'll have to make a copy to actually do something with it.

**But** ... copying won't give you the trigger I set up.  If you edit the script, go to the menu **Reources** --> **Current project's triggers** and make yourself a time-based trigger on the function *checkForChanges()*.  I set it for "every minute" for testing purposes.

To your columns I added four new ones:

- *concat* - is simply a concatenation of all the row values whose changes you need to monitor
- *Current Hash* - is generated from a simple function I added to your script
- *Last Edit* - after sending an email the script gives this cell the value of *Current Hash*
- *Changed* - Compares *Last Edit* and *Current Hash* and says **true* if they are different.

So ... periodically the function *checkForChanges()* runs down the range **ChangeDetector** looking for **true**.   If it finds nothing it quits immediately.

Each time it does find a change, it collects the data of that row and emails it. (Actually, I just log it, for simplicity sake.)

The key trick is the pair of lines :

```
  lastEdits[row_][0] = currentHashCodes[row_][0];
  ss_.getRangeByName("LastEdit").setValues(lastEdits);
```

Note how clear your code can be if you use **named ranges** where ever possible.

Here's the code in case the example gets lost someday in the future :

```
/* Called from cells in column "Current Hash" */
function strHash(valCell) {
  var hash = 0;
  if (valCell.length == 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < valCell.length; i++) {
    char = valCell.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
    hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }

  return hash;
}


/* Called periodically from a timed trigger. */
function checkForChanges() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var changeDetector = ss.getRangeByName("ChangeDetector").getValues();
  for (row in changeDetector) {
    if (row > 0) {
      changed = changeDetector[row][0];
      if (changed) notify(ss, row);
    }
  }

}


/* Called by checkForChanges(). */
function notify(ss_, row_) {

  initializeRangeArrays(ss_);

  status = statii[row_][0];
  project = projects[row_][0];
  task = tasks[row_][0];
  customer = customers[row_][0];
  executor = executors[row_][0];
  deadline = deadlines[row_][0];
  sendto = recipients[row_][0];

  var mysubject = status + ' | ' + project + ': ' + task + ' - ' + ss_.getName() + ' update';
  var mybody = '\nStatus: ' + status 
             + '\n\nproject: ' + project 
             + '\ncustomer: ' + customer 
             + '\ntask: ' + task
             + '\nexecutor: ' + executor
             + '\nDeadline: ' + deadline
             + '\n\n' + ss_.getName()
             + ': \n' + ss_.getUrl();

  Logger.log("to: " + sendto);
  Logger.log("subject: " + mysubject);
  Logger.log("body: " + mybody);
  Logger.log("");

  lastEdits[row_][0] = currentHashCodes[row_][0];
  ss_.getRangeByName("LastEdit").setValues(lastEdits);

}; 


var recipients = null;
var projects = null;
var customers = null;
var tasks = null;
var deadlines = null;
var executors = null;
var statii = null;
var lastEdits = null;
var currentHashCodes = null;

var rangeArraysInitialized = false;
/* Called by notify(). */
function initializeRangeArrays(ss_) {

  if (  !  rangeArraysInitialized  ) {
    recipients = ss_.getRangeByName("Recipient").getValues();
    projects = ss_.getRangeByName("Project").getValues();
    customers = ss_.getRangeByName("Customer").getValues();
    tasks = ss_.getRangeByName("Task").getValues();
    deadlines = ss_.getRangeByName("Date").getValues();
    statii = ss_.getRangeByName("Status").getValues();
    executors = ss_.getRangeByName("Executor").getValues();
    lastEdits = ss_.getRangeByName("LastEdit").getValues();
    currentHashCodes = ss_.getRangeByName("CurrentHash").getValues();

    rangeArraysInitialized = false;
  }
}
```

**Update 2014/09/22 :**

I have made a few changes in the demo spreadsheet.  Please take a peek.

To the script I added . . .

```
function strArrayHash(range) {
  var ret = new Array();
  var str = "";
  for (item in range) {
    str = range[item].toString();
    if (str.length > 0) {
      ret[item] = strHash(str);
      Utilities.sleep(50);      // play with this to reduce "internal execution error"s
    } else {
      ret[item] = "";
    }
  };
  return ret;
}
```

In column "P" I replaced . . .

```
=if( M2 = "", "", strHash(R2)))
=if( M3 = "", "", strHash(R3)))
      :
      :
=if( M22 = "", "", strHash(R22)))
```

. . . with . . .

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if( M2:M514 = "", "", strArrayHash(R2:R514)))
```

. . .  in cell "P2" **ONLY**.  I **also** deleted the contents of all cells in the range "P3:P22"

I increased the total number of rows to 1026

Once values appeared in column P, I copied cells P2:P1026 into M2:M1026 using [Paste Special] » [Paste values only].

In my i7 laptop it took it 30 seconds to recalc and detect a change in line 500.

I get an internal execution error if I try to do all 1024 lines.

Probably you will need to complicate the "if" clause such that it causes hash calculations on only the lines that really need it.

Update :: 2017/02/24 No one is interested in this so I stopped the trigger that ran the script.

Comment: Thx for answer. But I noticed two things:
- script is not that fast as is need to be (if I change something in row number 1 script is slowly checking all other rows for change...),
- somewhere around 300+ row (yes, my docs is that big, ~500 rows) I have an error: "Error: Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account."