# Sending an email whenever a cell is changed in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a script for a google spreadsheet that will email a specific person whenever a cell in Column M is modified to 'y'.  I found this script, 
[email notification if cell is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336907/email-notification-if-cell-is-changed)
and I am trying to modify it to suit my needs, but I am having an issue getting it to work.  This is my script as it stands now.

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(e)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(ss)
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sheet)
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  Logger.log(cell)
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  Logger.log(row)
  var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
  Logger.log(column)
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  Logger.log(cellvalue)
  var recipients = "08cylinders@gmail.com"; //email address will go here
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('M')!=-1){ 
message = sheet.getRange('M'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
} 
  Logger.log(message)
  Logger.log(cell)
  var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + to view the changes on row: ' + row; //New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For   message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
}
```

If anybody has an idea of what I'm missing, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Victor

Answer (score 0):

i think this may solve your event problem:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ssActive = e.source;
var ssActiveRange = ssActive.getActiveRange();
var ssActiveRangeVal = ssActiveRange.getValue();
var ActiveRow = ssActiveRange.getRow(); // if needed to put on body's message
var ActiveColumn = ssActiveRange.getColumn();

if((ssActiveRangeVal=='y' || ssActiveRangeVal=='Y') && ActiveColumn==13){ // ActiveColumn==13 for M
  // write down your mail code here
}
```

}

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for this.  I gave it a try, and while I can get it to run manually, if I set up a trigger, it doesn't work.  Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an email from the onEdit trigger. What you need to do is save the edits as a Document Property and then setup a 1-minute time based trigger that sends the content of the property in an email and flushes the queue.

Comment: Hi.  I don't quite understand what you mean.  Could you explain that a little more?  Thank you.