# Google Apps Script Email Notification When Cell Value Changes to Specific Text Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

OK, so I figured how my question isn't a duplicate, and how what I am looking for isn't resolved in the links given.

This is as close as I can get:

```
      function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Incoming POs");
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "test@gmail.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('K')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
   }
  var subject = 'PO# '+ sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue() + ' has been received';
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

The problem with this code is that I need the notification to be sent ONLY if a row has it's F column value changed to "Yes".  This code sends a notification any time anything is changed in column F.

Does that make sense?  Thanks for the help!  This is close, I just can't figure out how to incorporate required text contains rules.

> (Original text from original question: 'm developing a new Google
>   Sheet that three different people will use/share to collaborate on
>   some of their work. What I'm really after is writing a notification
>   script that will email other stakeholders when any cell in column F
>   gets its value changed to "Yes" in Sheet2 of the master sheet (I mean
>   "workbook" because the terminology for Google sheets is confusing vs
>   Excel because there are workbooks and sheets, but it seems like there
>   are just sheets...and sheets in Google).
>
> I want the email to contain some text, along with the value of cell A
>   in the row that has the F column value changed.)

Comment: Much more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336907/email-notification-if-cell-is-changed. And I'm sure there are others!

Comment: Dang!  I thought I searched for this problem already like a good forum user, but I guess I didn't have the right search terms or something.  I'll check these links out.  Sorry for the dup question!

Comment: You say the code is close; what isn't it doing correctly? Don't you just need to check the `cellValue` you've parsed out to see if they typed in 'yes', and then not send the message if it's not 'yes'?

Comment: I can get it to send emails when *any* change is made to column K, but I can't get it to send emails when K is changed from "No" to "Yes".   I have tried changing the if statement to `if(cell.indexOf('K')!=-1) && cellvalue=='Yes'` but that still just sends an email any time any change is made.  Still so unbelievably stuck on this...

Answer (score 0):

You should set an [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)( runs when a user changes a value in a preadsheet.) trigger to recognize the edit.

In the same function you can get the event object which has the details of the cell that has been edited. Then you use sheet[.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) to get the range of values to be added in the email message.

The result set from the getRange method would be a two dimensional array.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This wont work because you cant send emails from onEdit.

Comment: You need to add an installable edit trigger. I think the answer i linked above covers that.